# Mishearing something overheard

Tags: single-word-requests, compounds

Consider the following situation:

```
A & B are having a conversation. C overhears it.
Either A or B says something C considers controversial.
C later speaks about this in private, but has misheard.
```

Is there a single compound word that would cover this situation? I am thinking either **'overmisheard'** or **'misoverheard'**:

`"I'm sorry, I seem to have`**`overmisheard`**`you."`

or

`"I'm sorry, I seem to have`**`misoverheard`**`you."`

The latter seems more likely to me, as we're applying the negative prefix 'mis-' ([meaning 'incorrectly'](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mis-)) to the action of overhearing. I've checked the dictionary but am unable to come conclusively to an existing word so I would like to if there is a word for this or the correct construction for a compound word if there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Misoverheard** would be a more probable neologism.

First, while *overheard* is a common concept *over-* as a prefix wouldn't retain the sense of eavesdropping if added to *misheard*. In the Oxford English Dictionary, "over-, prefix," the *over-* in *overhear* or *oversee* is sense 1.o in a long list of senses (1.a through 1.n, and all the entries afterward to 3d). This indicates that [other meanings would easily interfere with your intended one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over-#English), like being spatially or temporally over something or doing something too many times.

Second, *mis-* would preserve the sense of mistaken action when applied to *overheard*. In the OED your intended sense is the first entry listed:

> a. Prefixed to verbs, with sense ‘badly’, ‘wrongly’, ‘perversely’, ‘mistakenly’, ‘amiss’.

*Mis-* commonly does this even today. I could say *[misclicked](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misclick)*, for instance, to mean I mistakenly clicked, just like I can say I *misoverheard* to say I mistakenly overheard. Over coinages would make sense: I *misliked* a social media post or *mistweeted* an update. However, saying I *[overclicked](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=over-click)*, *overliked*, or *overtweeted* would more likely lead people to think that I had clicked, liked, or tweeted too many times for a given function.

Finally, just to confirm which sense people go with more often, a Google search illustrates that *[misoverheard](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&q=%22misoverheard%22)* is occasionally used or coined with about 1890 results as of this writing, whereas *[overmisheard](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&q=%22overmisheard%22)* has 9 results, one of which is this question. That suggests *misoverheard* is far more likely to be understood in use.

Comment: Did you mean 'misoverhood' in your opening sentence, or was that a slip?

Comment: It was a Froodian slip. My bad. :)

Comment: I wish people would explain downvotes when making them because aside of that now corrected error, I don't see anything wrong with your answer.

Comment: Alright, it's been a couple days so I'm marking as accepted. Thanks!